# Unmount all your partitions to release/free up SSD

Tags: linux, udev, ssd, unmounting, squashfs

I have a machine with a single SSD and 3 partitions. I want to unmount the entire SSD while staying live so that I can run a firmware upgrade tool on the SSD. I know that unmounting your only disk is not recommended but I figure this is okay in my case since my rootfs is a squashfs which loaded into memory during boot, and the kernel, theoretically, is also mounted in memory. That's why I believe we can unmount all partitions, run the firmware upgrade, and then reboot the system to get back to normal state.

My problem: I cannot unmount `sda1`

I am able to unmount `sda2` (storage space) and `sda3` (where some log files are stashed) after repeatedly running the following 2-3 times:

```
fuser -mv /dev/sda1 -k -9
fuser -mv /dev/sda2 -k -9
fuser -mv /dev/sda3 -k -9

umount -f /dev/sda1
umount -f /dev/sda2
umount -f /dev/sda3
```

At that point, running

```
fuser -mv /dev/sda1
fuser -mv /dev/sda2
fuser -mv /dev/sda3
```

produces the output

```
                    USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/sda1:           root     kernel mount /boot
```

That tells me that the `sda2` and `sda3` unmounted successfully but that kernel does not want to let go of the `sda1`. No matter what I try, `sda1` does not unmount

I have also tried to kill the only process linked to sda1 through:

```
$ ps -ef | grep sda
root       423     2  0 00:19 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
$ kill -9 423
```

but no luck there either.

**Note**: I can't use any other hardware like a USB stick to help throughout the process.

**Update**:
`lsblk` produces the following

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   3.8G  0 disk 
|-sda2   8:2    0   1.9G  0 part 
|-sda3   8:3    0 949.2M  0 part 
`-sda1   8:1    0   957M  0 part /boot
```

Comment: `Jbd` is the [journaling block device](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/jbd2-sda1-8-what-exactly-is-this-process-that-keeps-running-every-few-seconds-788810/). On what is `sda1` mounted? The output of `lsblk` could help clarifying that. You could also try `umount -l`. If it's only `jdb` that is blocking the device, it may work because `jdb` should be running periodically and [`umount -l`](https://superuser.com/questions/412109/lazy-umount-or-unmounting-a-busy-disk-in-linux) should "trigger" at the right time between the executions. It may take some time though.

Comment: Need to double check this, but I believe squashfs decompresses the filesystem on the fly rather rather than at mount time, so it still needs read access to the SSD. If you want a filesystem that works entirely from memory, you might want to try ramdisk or ramfs (via initrd or initramfs, or by doing a chroot/pivot_root into it) rather than squashfs

Comment: @rudib, I update my question to include `lsblk` output. I also have tried to use `umount -l` in the past but the `jbd2` process still hangs on to `sda1`.

Comment: @LieRyan, squashfs does decompress on the fly and when squashfs is mounted, the squashfs file is loaded into memory. So linux decompresses on the fly using the copy of the squashfs file that had been loaded to memory at the time of mounting. I ran a test by mounting a squashfs file on a loop device. I then deleted the original squashfs and I could still navigate and view files in the mounted file system. I also noticed that memory usage increased exactly by size of the squashfs file.

Comment: This might not be a perfect solution and may cause damage to the partition: you could open two terminals and do `umount -l` and then `kill -9` in the other. This should trigger the unmount after the kill...

Comment: Also: what does the `fstab` entry or the output of `cat /proc/mounts` look like? I've read that a double commit value might cause problems with `jbd2`.

Comment: @Frankie: Your test was inconclusive. In Linux, files can exist on disk without a filename as long as there's still at least one process with an open file handle to it. You can delete a file from the filesystem after the file is opened, but the file will still be perfectly usable for reading and writing to the drive, it'll still use disk space, and it'll still lock up the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, [Lie Ryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1989/lie-ryanhttp://). The reason why I could not unmount the SSD is beacause rootfs was still using the squashfs file from the SSD. The squashfs file is not loaded in to memory as I had believed but instead it's decompressed on the fly from the original file on the SSD.